# simple thread code always crashes firefox extension (nsIThreadManager)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

While creating a simple thread in firefox (Aurora 30) this always crashes.

All this does is execute function "task" from the thread

any idea what's going wrong?

```
function task(a, b) {
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
}

thread_job = {

    init: function(func, param1, param2) {
        this.func = func
        this.param1 = param1
        this.param2 = param2
        alert("inside init");
    },

    run: function(){
        this.func(this.param1, this.param2);
    }
}

var thread = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"] // create thread
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIThreadManager)
                .newThread(0);

// init the object "thread_job" to a simple function
thread_job.init(task,1,2);

//extension code 
thread.dispatch(thread_job, thread.DISPATCH_NORMAL);//dispatch the thread
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_Thread_Manager), the nsIThreadManager can only be called from c++. Javascript callees should use workers, instead.